# Proving Two Standard Normal Variables Are Uncorrelated

Tags: probability, self-study, correlation, normal-distribution, independence

> Let $X \sim N(0,1)$, a random variable $U$ does not depend on $X$, and $P(U = 1) = P(U = -1) = 1/2$. Finally $Y = UX$. Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.

$Y$ should also be standard normal due to the symmetry of the normal distribution. I know that independent implies uncorrelated, but $X$ and $Y$ are clearly dependent variables.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Adding the `self-study` tag is not enough, you should indicate why computing the correlation proves itself a challenge to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may sound counterintuitive, but having them connected via an equation doesn't mean they're correlated. Clearly, $$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]=E[UX^2]=E[U]E[X^2]=0$$

And, having two normal RVs uncorrelated doesn't mean they're independent. Independence is implied **only when** the two are **jointly normal**.

Comment: How did you get the last two equations? $E[UX^2]=E[U]E[X^2]=0$? I thought $E(AB) \neq E(A) E(B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are random variables in general. Also how did you find the expected values of $U$ and $X^2$?

Comment: @Pame You've said $U$ and $X$ are independent. Also, $$E[U]=(1/2)\times 1+(1/2)\times(-1)=0$$
No need to find $E[X^2]$

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind this exercise is that **when you randomly switch the sign of a variable** (with equal probabilities of positive and negative), **you eliminate any correlation it might have with any other variable**, provided that correlation existed in the first place.

In this general setting, then, let $(X,Z)$ be *any* bivariate random variable for which both $X$ and $Z$ have finite nonzero variances (which, after choosing suitable units of measurement, can be taken to equal $1$), let $U$ be independent of $X$ as in the question, and define $Y=UZ.$  **We will show $Y$ is uncorrelated with $X.$**

---

Observe, from the definition of variance (first and fourth lines below) and the fact $U^2=1$ (third line) that

$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{Var}(Y) &= E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2 = E[(UZ)^2]-E[UZ]^2 \\&\le E[(UZ)^2] = E[U^2Z^2] \\&=E[Z^2] \\&= E[Z]^2 + \operatorname{Var}(Z) \\&= E[Z]^2+1.
}$$

Because this implies $$|\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)|^2\le \operatorname{Var}(X)\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{Var}(Y)\le E[Z]^2+1 \lt \infty,$$ **the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ exists and is finite.**

Since $U$ and $-U$ are identically distributed and independent of $X,$

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{Cov}(X,UZ)=\operatorname{Cov}(X,-UZ)=-\operatorname{Cov}(X,UZ)=-\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y).$$

The only finite number equal to its negative is $0.$  The correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is a multiple of this covariance and therefore also is zero, *QED.*

---

The original problem concerns the special case where $Z=X$ and $X$ has a standard Normal distribution.